# How to automatically expand child relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

When I run a query I can see the nodes correctly. But I need to go one by one and click "Expand child relationships" which is tedious and time consuming. Is there any way to see the graph with everything already expanded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about Neo4j Browser, right? 
If so, you need to specify exactly what you need to visualize first. So let's say you have a `User` node that is connected to a `Book` node with a `read` relationship.
Instead of just

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN u
```

And expanding that node to see all other connected nodes, just do

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:read]->(b:Book)
RETURN *
```

And just add the relationships you want in the query itself.

You can, however, do

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

Which will return every node with its relationship, but there's a limit to how many nodes you can see. You can extend the limit in the settings (bottom left of the navigation bar) and tinkering with `Graph Visualization` values. This is not recommended and, depending on the size of your graphdb, it could cause a bottleneck and it can take a **lot** of time.

My advice, just write a query that shows exactly which nodes and relationships you want to see.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So as per your advice, say I want to return only graphs with at least n nodes. How would I do that?

Comment: if you do `MATCH (u:User) RETURN u` it will return all user nodes nodes with the limit set in the settings. Depending on the amount of users your graphdb has, it can take a long time. It's always good practice to set a limit in your query `MATCH (u:User) RETURN u LIMIT 100`

Comment: Thanks again. I'm not sure I explained myself correctly though. I meant if I want to return graphs with at least n nodes where all of the graphs are automatically expanded.
Also, I understand your point about limiting the query. Is there a way, for example, I could return up to 100 graphs - each with at least n nodes - and expand them completely?

Answer (score 0):

The Neo4j Browser supports an "auto-completion" mode that, when enabled, automatically queries for (and displays) the relationships between the nodes returned by a Cypher query.

In the most recent versions of the Browser, you can enable auto-completion mode by clicking the gear icon on the left side, scrolling to the bottom of the Browser Settings panel, and check-marking the "Connect result nodes" option.